# Efficient way to create array of integer days from today in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, date

I'm trying to build an array of days using `date(z)` days of year format, starting with today, and stepping through a set number of days.

I've figured out a solution to this, but it doesn't feel like it's the most efficient, maybe there is a built-in function in PHP for this.

Current solution:

```
$today = date(z);
$count = 3;
$array = array();
$i = 0;
while ($i < $count) {
  $array[] = $today + $i;
  $i++;
}

print_r($array);
```

Outputs correctly to this: `Array ( [0] => 297 [1] => 298 [2] => 299 )`

Any other better solutions?

Comment: I wouldn't call this a bad approach. Maybe a `for` loop would be better than the `while`.

Comment: What's the desired behavior when `$count` is high enough to cross years?

Comment: @PatrickQ hadn't considered it, in my use case that would not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `range` - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

> range — Create an array containing a range of elements

So let's take today:

```
$today = date('z');
$range = range($today, $today + $count);
```

Comment: Would `range($today, $today+$count);` (or similar) be better?

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for that; for my use case I need the array ONLY to have the days specified, not the entire 365 so this would work better.